# Changed Selenium Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am using this Selenium Set-Up in an older Project. (later called "Old-Project")
[image]

Now I want to migrate this test to a Project with this Set-Up: (later called "New-Project)
[image]

I am using a code sample like this for the Old-Project:
[image]

But in the new Project I face the following Error:
[image]
Does somebody know how to implement this code for the New-Project?

Regards
Alex

Comment: My advice is write the automation from scratch.  Right now you are like 3 blind men feeling an elephant ('a snake!', 'a pillar!', 'a wall!').  You don't know the details of what you are doing and you are guessing and hoping.  Start from scratch, study what you need today and put it together.  You might need to read a few books and get up to speed on selenium today.  You are showing stuff that was in use 10 years ago

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the advice. Can you give me a book recommendation?

Comment: I would start on the selenium site.  It is not well laid out and much of the information is on obsolete stuff.  So look specifically for webdriver stuff on this page: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp  If you're going to get into automation more you're gonna want to pick a language. I recommend Ruby as it has a good track record in this space.  I don't know of any good books in this area.  I would look to online coding course and I am out-of-date with what sites are best to use now.  My advice on selenium books is 8+ years outdated which is ancient in tech terms.